# restrict insertion of data entry to Parse database except admin

Tags: javascript, jquery, parse-platform, admin

I've created a simple page ('admin.html') with the form contents like question text, 4 options and correct answer id. I'm able to add all the contents of this form to parse database using jQuery after validations. But currently the 'Questions' class has public read, write access. Anyone (logged-in user) visiting this page can add questions to the database. I want to restrict this behavior. I want only user with admin role to have access to the admin page.

FYI, I have created admin role with current logged in user by following instructions from this link: https://www.parse.com/questions/role-cant-assign-user-in-js

Comment: can you provide code so we can understand what you have done

Comment: my best advice would be to do a deep dive into Parse's SDK documentation regarding ACLs, roles and users. I know Parse makes it pretty easy for you to set who has read and write access to the database values, but I don't know it off the top of my head. I do however know that it's there in the docs.

Comment: @VRK the code is working fine, since it's just a form and adding data it to database is successful. So, I don't think it's necessary to share code here. Regarding role and users, I've given link above. It's the same code I've used.

Comment: @jdogg I think I need to somehow block the logged in user by checking the role is admin or not. Currently I'm looking into docs for more information. Also class-level permissions are working. I hope to get a proper working solution using the ACLs and CLPs. Thanks for help.